# publish dll of single page visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

I have website which is around 700 Mb in size.

now when I change something in code behind, then every time to i have to publish website  to replace .dll server. because we are using single assembly for single page. now for build and publish consumes around 20 minutes.

I have installed visual  studio 2013 for publishing single page. but when I published single page, it just publish .aspx and .aspx.cs page in visual studio.

What do  I have to do to only publish single page into dll. so I don't have to publish whole website again and again?

Comment: edited question. want to publish single page into single dll . so i dont have to go through process of publishing whole website.

Comment: You must do publish for entire website.

Comment: If you are using single assembly per page, why it takes 20 minutes? It should take such time if the entire project is one assembly only

Comment: @Kilanny website is around 700 mb in source. for publishing first it will build and then it will publish. thats y.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build/Publish Single Page of Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Web Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942052/build-publish-single-page-of-visual-studio-2013-asp-net-web-site)