# Build/Publish Single Page of Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Web Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a ASP.net web project that was migrated from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013.

In VS 2010 when working on a page and it's respective code-behind you could right click the page in the solution explorer and click "Build/Publish" page and it would compile the aspx and cs into their respective aspx and dll files.

In VS 2013 things moved around a bit. You must now Build/Publish the entire web site. There is however an option if you right click the page you want to publish. However, all it does is stick the aspx and the code-behind in your "web_deploy" folder and that doesn't exactly work when you go to push it to your production environment...so my question is:

**How can I publish a single page from my web project using visual studio 2013 without having to publish the entire site?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publishing a single page is not recommended.  As far as I remember ... VS never supported this ...

The risk of incompatible assemblies is very high.  Updating the HTML only portion of a single page could work ... but again ... not recommended ... and is bad practice

The reason why publishing a single page is not recommended (nor supported) is because the code in each page is compiled into a separate page assembly.  References to objects outside of that page are updated during the build process.  Taking the built assembly for that page and inserting it into a web application does not guarantee that the linkages are consistent.  At best it is considered "undefined behavior".  It may work, but doing such in a production environment is poor practice.

Comment: What about cases where web sites are a few hundred megs plus? You must compile the entire site even if you made a two line change in the code-behind of one page?

Comment: That is correct.  The size of a web application should have been considered during it's design and build phase.  You might need a project to split the app into smaller components if that is a big concern.

Comment: very inconvenient. Could you explain further the 'risk of incompatible assemblies'?

Comment: It has been supported in VS before, but I agree it's not recommended. It might look handy, but it's only for small sites where you don't actually need it.